# Using Error Control Operators to allow try catch to handle errors

Tags: design, design-patterns, php, error-handling

There are a few functions in php that throw errors when they fail, such as `ftp_login`. If I have this code.

```
try {
    $result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, 'incorrectPassword');
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Could not login.');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . ' - ' . error_get_last();
}
```

It will not catch because of the error. Is the appropriate thing in this case to use an Error Control Operator like so?

```
try {
    $result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, 'incorrectPassword');
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Could not login.');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . ' - ' . error_get_last();
}
```

This allows me to react to the error, however it suppresses errors and would be a major performance hit. How can I judge which is the right approach, and is there any other alternatives I'm not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your own error handler with `set_error_handler`. Within that error handler, throw the exception.

If now `ftp_open` throws an error, the exception from your custom error handler behave just as if `ftp_open` threw it.

Comment: I know this is not a debugging site, but how could I apply set_error_handler to this function? I'm having trouble applying the information in the docs to this situation. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: A error handler is called when a php error occurs; it overrides the default behaviour (which is printing the error out)